# Hibernate Error Cannot open connection

Tags: hibernate

got the following error:

> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open
>   connection    at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:105)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1561)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.iterate(QueryLoader.java:392)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.iterate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:318)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performIterate(HQLQueryPlan.java:177)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.iterate(SessionImpl.java:1156)    at
>   org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.iterate(QueryImpl.java:46)   at
>   com.vis.erp.common.reports.accountbooks.vatreport.VatMainMethod.getVatList(VatMainMethod.java:108)
>     at
>   com.vis.erp.common.reports.accountbooks.vatreport.VatMainMethod.main(VatMainMethod.java:59)
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link
>   failure

but have not used any jdbc query in the program

so pls help 
thanks in advance..

Comment: Please Add your source code here .It would be helpful for all of us to understand your prob clearly and can find the answer easily.

Comment: Please put in source code pointed by the exception trace...

Answer (score 0):

give the database port number with `url` and your problem will be resolved, for example:

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=abc_db</property>
```